# Need to verify value in binary digit in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is my problem. For example I have a binary digit 0010010 and I only need to verify that third value, from left to right, is 1. How do I do that in T-SQL ?

```
-- Addded estimated hours field  

SET @EstHours = (SELECT SUM(ESTHOURS)
FROM LABORMP
WHERE  @PMID = LABORMP.PMID AND ( LEFT(CYCLETYPE,3) = 1 OR LABORMP.CYCLETYPE is null)
)
```

Comment: What's the data type of `CYCLETYPE`? if it's varchar, use forpas's answer. If it's varbinary, use mine.

Comment: It is varchar(7)

Comment: Than use the answer by forpas. That should solve your problem. I'm leaving my answer even though it doesn't fit the question because it might help future readers using `varbinary` and not `varchar`.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I will give points for both of you. Please mark as a good question if you think it is. Best, Min

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `substring()` to get the 3d digit and convert to `bit`, which will return `True` or `False`:

```
declare @binary varchar(8) = '00100010'
select CONVERT(bit, substring(@binary, 3, 1))
```

returns

```
True --1
```

and

```
declare @binary varchar(8) = '00000010'
select CONVERT(bit, substring(@binary, 3, 1))
```

returns

```
False --0
```

**Edit**:
For your query you just need:

```
...SUBSTRING(CYCLETYPE, 3, 1) = '1' ...
```

if `CYCLETYPE` is a string.
Your query's logic can be writen like this:

```
SET @EstHours = (
  SELECT SUM(ESTHOURS)
  FROM LABORMP
  WHERE  
    @PMID = PMID 
    AND 
    SUBSTRING(COALESCE(CYCLETYPE, '111'), 3, 1) = '1'
)
```

Comment: Posted my query. Any thoughts on that ?

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I will give points for both of you. Please mark as a good question if you think it is. Best, Min

Answer (score 1):

If the value is varbinary, you can use the [bitwise and operator (`&`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-and-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
DECLARE @binaryValue varbinary(7) = 0010010;

SELECT 1
WHERE @binaryValue & 0010000 = 0010000
```

Comment: Posted my query. Any thoughts on that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 1
FROM yourtable
WHERE SUBSTRING(yourcolumn, 3, 1) = 1
```

You will get an empty result if the third digit is not 1

Comment: it will also return an empty result if the first or second digits is not `0` - `left('101000', 3) returns `101`.

Comment: Posted my query. Any thoughts on that ?